# Hamiltonians on tensor product states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics

Solid state & Atomic Physics.

The wavefunction for the electrons is $\psi(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{R})$, where $\mathbf{r}$ is the position of the electron and $\mathbf{R}$ of the nucleus.
The wavefunction for the nucleus is $\phi(\mathbf{R})$.
The total wavefunction, $\Psi(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{R})=\psi(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{R})\phi(\mathbf{R})$.

The Hamiltonian is $H = Kinetic_{electrons}(\mathbf{r})+Kinetic_{electrons}(\mathbf{R}) + Potential_{electrons}(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{R})$,

and I am ignoring the electron-electron repulsion (depending on $\mathbf{r}$).

Now, I want to do this in Dirac notation:

$\psi(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{R}) \Leftrightarrow |\psi\rangle$,

$\phi(\mathbf{R}) \Leftrightarrow |\phi\rangle$,

$\Psi(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{R})=\psi(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{R})\phi(\mathbf{R}) \Leftrightarrow |\Psi\rangle = |\psi\rangle \otimes |\phi\rangle$.

$H = K_e + K_N + V_{N-e}$.

How do I write the Hamiltonian in terms of $H_{something} \otimes H_{else}$?

Or if this isn't possible, how would I solve this problem in Dirac notation?

Comment: $\psi(r,R)\phi(R)$ does *not* look like a tensor product to me, since $\psi(r,R)$ depends on both $r$ and $R$, while a tensor product state in the product of the electron's space and the nucleus' space should look like $\psi(r)\phi(R)$.

Comment: So how can I write $\psi(r,R)\phi(R)$ in Dirac notation?